# Aggregating multiple results from go routines into a single array

Tags: go, channel

I have the following function which spins off a given amount of go routines

```
func (r *Runner) Execute() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    wg.Add(len(r.pipelines))
    for _, p := range r.pipelines {
        go executePipeline(p, &wg)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    errs := ....//contains list of errors reported by any/all go routines

}
```

I was thinking there might be some way with channels, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Create a slice of size `len(r.pipelines)` and let every worker write to their corresponding index.

Comment: There is a pattern for combining results of some channels into one named Fan In. You could use the approach in that pattern (not necessarily the pattern itself).

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is using mutexes if you can make executePipeline retuen errors:

```
// ...
for _, p := range r.pipelines {
    go func(p pipelineType) {
        if err := executePipeline(p, &wg); err != nil {
            mu.Lock()
            errs = append(errs, err)
            mu.UnLock()
        }
    }(p)
}
```

To use a channel, you can have a separate goroutine listning for errors:

```
errCh := make(chan error)

go func() {
    for e := range errCh {
        errs = append(errs, e)
    }
}
```

and in the `Execute` function, make the following changes:

```
// ...
wg.Add(len(r.pipelines))
for _, p := range r.pipelines {
    go func(p pipelineType) {
        if err := executePipeline(p, &wg); err != nil {
            errCh <- err
        }
    }(p)
}

wg.Wait()
close(errCh)
```

You can always use @zerkms method listed above if the number of goroutines is not high.

instead of returning error from `executePipleline` and using a anonymous function wrapper, you can always make above changes within the function itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use channels as @Kaveh Shahbazian suggested:

```
func (r *Runner) Execute() {
    pipelineChan := makePipeline(r.pipelines)

    for cnt := 0; cnt < len(r.pipelines); cnt++{
        //recieve from channel
        p := <- pipelineChan
        //do something with the result 
    }
}

func makePipeline(pipelines []pipelineType) <-chan pipelineType{
    pipelineChan := make(chan pipelineType)

    go func(){
        for _, p := range pipelines {
           go func(p pipelineType){
              pipelineChan <- executePipeline(p)
           }(p)
        }
    }()
    return pipelineChan
}
```

Please see this example: https://gist.github.com/steven-ferrer/9b2eeac3eed3f7667e8976f399d0b8ad